# Why some Libraries failed to open?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, libraries, ld

I wrote a simple C Program, prova.c
`int main() {return 0;}`
I wanted to look at the libraries that were linked to it,so:

- I compiled it with `gcc -Wall -m32 -stdc=99 -c prova.c -o prova.o`
- I linked it `gcc -m32 -Wl,--verbose prova.o -o prova`

Now, when I examine my stadard ouput, I noticed some Libraries failed to open.
Why does this happen? Why they're attempted to open? Why does it fail?

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crti.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crti.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtbegin.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtbegin.o
attempt to open prova.o succeeded
prova.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_s.so succeeded
```

Comment: "Why they're linked if they are not opened?" they are not. When it see `-lgcc`, the linker tries to satisfy it with libgcc.so, which fails, so it tries libgcc.a next.

Comment: @MarcGlisse This should be an answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help me out! I edited the question so that it's more clear what I meant to ask. The quesiton I asked was not clear.

Comment: I'm wondering why the linker try to open them, and then why does them fail to open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compilation command has a shadow `-lgcc -lc` suffix, added by compiler driver. This flag does not tell linker precisely where libgcc and libc are to be found, nor it specifies whether they should be static or shared. So linker repeatedly tries to locate them in various directories (passed from compiler via `-L` or in linker script). By default, linker first tries to link the shared version of the library (`.so`), then the static one (`.a`).

Warnings that you see `attempt to open ... failed` are not real failures but diagnostic messages about linker's progress in searching needed libs.